# How can I detect rewritten url's when using curl

Tags: php, curl

So I am using curl to get the first image listed on a page if no og data exists. I then save the image locally to a cache folder for faster future calling.

A problem has arisen when the url in question is a rewrite.

For example, in a general situation `http://someurl.com/dir` will return the first image found on the page. Lets say in the source that is `src="img/image.jpg"`. I then save a copy of `http://someurl.com/dir/img/image.jpg` to my local directory.

The problem comes in when `dir` is actually a rewrite. Say `http://someurl.com/dir` is actually `http://someurl.com/?username=dir`. In such an instance `http://someurl.com/dir/img/image.jpg` will return a 404 error because the file is actually located at `http://someurl.com/img/image.jpg`.

So I am wondering how I could actually check if the url is a rewrite and how I would handle this.

Keep in mind this is a simple example. Its possible the url is  `http://someurl.com/dir/user/post/type/` and that `dir`, `user`, `post`, and `type` is all just one giant rewrite and `src="img/image.jpg"` is still actually the base path `/`.

Sites like facebook seem to be able to handle such rewrites fairly easily and still get the image and I am totally baffled how its done.

Comment: `Sites like facebook seem to be able to handle such rewrites fairly easily and still get the image and I am totally baffled how its done`
Can you provide an example on this? How can you say that facebook is able to handle url rewrite?

Comment: I can't off the top of my head, I just know in my blogging experience that facebook has not had problems getting images even though most wordpress sites are entirely rewritten url's and I have never seen google not be able to grab a cache copy for its image search even though its read from a re-written blog url. Perhaps thats because wordpress is so widely used everyone knows the paths already?

Comment: start at the base path '/', and request the image, if the header returns 404, not found, send a new request up until the nest base path separator '/dir'... and keep going until you find what you are looking for, just like a simple php based web crawler can do.

Comment: You may be confusing rewriting with redirecting. If you request `/dir/user/post/type/` and it does a *rewrite* (e.g. with Apache mod_rewrite) to some other URL, and the output references `img/image.jpg`, then your browser is going to request `/dir/user/post/type/img/image.jpg`, so that had better be there. If it's doing a *redirect* (i.e. responding with a 302 code), then the image is going to be relative to that other URL. If the latter is your situation, you can tell cURL not to follow redirects but rather handle them yourself, or you might be able to extract the new URL from a header.

Comment: Also note that `/dir` is different from `/dir/` for the purposes of relative URLs. An image of `img/image.jpg` referenced from `/dir` is going to come from `/img/image.jpg`, not `/dir/img/image.jpg`.

Comment: @GregSchmidt you are wrong, sorry. I was referring to rewritten url's exactly as described in the post. With or without the / the browser will treat it as the web server tells it to. It doesn't automatically add a / to the end of a directory. You can call `https://myurl.com/mydir` just as well as `https://myurl.com/mydir/` and it will treat both exactly the same so if `index.php` calls `img/image.jpg` in both instances, the proper image location is returned. Both cases `/mydir` and `/mydir/` could be a re-write of ?path=mydir It depends how you tell the server to serve it.

Comment: @StephanieTemple I suppose that could work. Will have to explode the url and get all the sub parts to do that, but should work. Thanks.